# Obfuscating personal data in MySQL backup

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, backup

Tell me how to solve the problem with depersonalizing personal data of clients in the MySQL database. My task is to make personal data of clients depersonalized during backup - full name, email. There is an e-commerce CMS, and I want this data to be changed during backup. How to implement this? Are there any examples? I imagine this as data changes during backup on the fly. Another option is a copy of the database and data changes through sql queries, and then anonymous backup. Tell me how to do it right and if possible an example. Thanks.

Comment: You can either write your own export script (then this question is on topic on this site, but may require you to provide some code you have a problem with), or use a tool that does this already - but asking for a tool recommendation is off-topic on stackoverflow. Maybe it helps to know that there *are* tools that do that, and that what you are trying to do is called "sanitization". That term, together with e.g. mysqldump or mysql export in a search engine of your choice should give you some tools (or a starting point to write your own script) you can choose from.

Comment: do you have some examples with mysqldump and bash ? for me it looks like i need create dump, then import this dump in temp db, and then run some sql commands, and then create dump with Obfuscating personal data.

Comment: No, I don't have a prepared script for this, and there isn't only one way to do it (right). Your option sounds viable, especially if this is a one-time thing. Similar to e.g. [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/70019).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with GDPR data by the usual data masking by MySQL functions.

```
mysql -u %DB_LOGIN% -p%DB_PASSWORD% %GDPR_DB_NAME% -e "DROP DATABASE %GDPR_DB_NAME%"

mysql -u %DB_LOGIN% -p%DB_PASSWORD% -e "CREATE DATABASE %GDPR_DB_NAME%"

mysqldump -u %DB_LOGIN% -p%DB_PASSWORD% %DB_NAME% | mysql -u %DB_LOGIN% -p%DB_PASSWORD% %GDPR_DB_NAME%

mysql -u %DB_LOGIN% -p%DB_PASSWORD% -D %GDPR_DB_NAME% -e "UPDATE "customer_address_entity" SET company = CONCAT(SUBSTR(company, 1, 6), REPEAT('*', CHAR_LENGTH(company) - 6));" -vvv
```